# When can "that was" be omitted?

Tags: grammar

Unless I missed it, I have only found posts about omitting "that" and one for "which was" but not specifically similar to this question.

In this sentence: "Sometimes, he would borrow one of Jim’s soccer balls and kick it against at a wall **that was** spray-painted *hello* in red and *world* in blue."

"Sometimes, he would borrow one of Jim’s soccer balls and kick it against at a wall spray-painted *hello* in red and *world* in blue."

If I remove "that was" it sounds a bit weird, but is it grammatically correct? Does it read better one way or the other? What are the rules regarding this?

Furthermore, is it correct to say the "...at a wall that was spray-painted *hello*..." Do I have to say something like "spray-painted **with the words** *hello*..."

Best,

Comment: Yes, it's fine. In "kick it against a wall [that was spray-painted ...]", the bracketed bit is a relative clause modifying "wall". In "kick it against a wall [spray-painted ...]" the bracketed bit also modifies "wall", but this time it's a past-participial clause, not a relative one. Semantically there is no real difference between the two. Syntactically, the past-participial clause is a bare passive, the kind without the "be" or "get" marker.

Comment: thanks @BillJ. do you have an opinion on which reads better (w/ or w/o "that was")? also, do you have an opinion on the 2nd part "with the words"? If I don't need that either, then if understand correctly this sentence wording then is fine/best: "Sometimes, he would borrow one of Jim’s soccer balls and kick it against at a wall spray-painted hello in red and world in blue." (somehow it feels it might be clunky, but I've lost perspective :))

Comment: I'd say that most people would use the gerund-participial clause, since it's more succinct. "Spray-painted hello in red and world in blue" is fine. Don't use more words than you have to.

Comment: Btw, I would put the colours in 'scare' quotes: Spray-painted "hello" in red and "world" in blue.